# Как извлечь из массива все значения, кроме последних двух в php

Tags: массивы, php

Всем привет.
Как извлечь из массива все значения (любое количество), кроме последних двух или трех в php?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Для обычных массивов

```
$arr=explode(" ", "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0");
var_dump(array_slice($arr, 0, sizeof($arr)-2));
```

Для ассоциативных массивов

```
$arr=array("a"=>12, "b"=>13, "c"=>14, "d"=>15);
var_dump(array_slice($arr, 0, sizeof($arr)-2, true));
```

Comment: тьфу-ты. =) Совершенно вылетело из головы.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_all_exept($num,$arr,$begin=false){
  for($i=0;$i<$num,count($arr);$i++){//пока в массиве есть элементы вынимаем num элементов
    if($begin){//Вынимаем из начала или из конца
      array_shift($arr);
    }else{
      array_pop($arr);
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

Работает даже для ассоциативных массивов. 
Если массив с числовыми ключами, расположенными последовательно от 0, то все еще проще: по циклу вынимаем.

```
for($i=num;$i<count($arr);$i++)
```

для всех, кроме трех первых

```
for($i=0;$i<(count($arr))-$num;$i++)
```

для всех, кроме трех последних

Answer (score 0):

В каком смысле извлечь? Если имелось ввиду извлечь в другой массив, то можно так:

```
 <?php
    $a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    $b = array();
    if (count($a) >= 2) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($a) - 2; $i++) {
            $b[$i] = $a[$i];
        }    
    } else {
        echo "В массиве меньше двух элементов!";
    }
    var_dump($a, $b);
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, примерно так...

```
<?php
$arr[] = 1; // элемент массива
$arr[] = 3; // элемент массива
$arr[] = 5; // элемент массива
$result = count($arr)-2; // длинна всего массива за минусом двух последних элементов
// $result == 3 
echo $result; // на экран получим 1
?>
```

Comment: Не хотелось бы говорить очевидные вещи, но вместо первых трёх строчек можно написать `$arr = [1, 3 ,5];`